# Has jQuery an 'animating'-event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects, jquery-callback

Has jQuery an `animating`-event (not `:animated`)? Something like [`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step), but as extra method/event?

Currently I trigger a custom event in each animations step-function:

```
$('.foo').animate({property: 'value'}, {
    step: function(now, fx){
        $(this).trigger('animating', [now, fx])
    }
});

$('.foo').on('animating', function(e, now, fx){
    // do what you want
});
```

I think there's somewhere in the wild assuredly a better solution. Any ideas/approaches?

**Update**

I've written a (of course **not** awesome) special event, what make's handling this problem a bit easier:

```
(function($){
    var oldStep = $.fx.step._default;
    jQuery.event.special.animating = { };
    $.fx.step._default = function( fx ) {
        $(fx.elem).trigger('animating', fx);
        oldStep.apply( this, arguments );
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This doesn't work with jQuery 1.7+ since jQuery's animation method was changed, or rather the step function is not longer extendable ($.fx.step results in an empty `object`).

`jQuery.fx` refers to `Tween.prototype.init;`
&
`jQuery.fx.step` to `{};`

So it can't work...

I look still further on every tip!

Comment: There is nothing built-in, the next best would be to simply do what you are already doing: trigger your own event.

Comment: What you have now seems like overkill for a simple function call `doCustomEvent(e, now, fx);` Do you want a different action to happen on each step?

Comment: @CosminPascu Yes! The best way would if the new (custom)-`event` behaves like the original.

Comment: What about adding a `switch(stepNr)` inside the `step: function(){}` which would trigger a different function on each step case? Considering you know how many steps your animation goes through.

Comment: @CosminPascu Interesting thought... However that does not solve my problem ;) And by the way, you can get the number of all steps through `fx.start` and `fx.end`...