# How to extend jQuery's animate-step function

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery, jquery-callback, custom-events

Any ideas how to extend the `step`-function in jQuery 1.6+?

I've made a special-event to trigger a `custom-event` on each animated step. However since jQuery's animation method was changed, or rather the step function is not longer extendable (`$.fx.step` results in an empty `object`) is it impossible to extend it with your own things.

```
(function($){
    var oldStep = $.fx.step._default;
    $.event.special.animating = { };
    $.fx.step._default = function( fx ) {
        $(fx.elem).trigger('animating', fx);
        oldStep.apply( this, arguments );
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#foo').animate({width: 200});
$('#foo').bind('animating', function(e, fx){
    console.log(fx);
});
```

Any ideas how to get this to work with newer jQuery versions?

Comment: Looks like the function is now at `$.Tween.propHooks._default.set`. But neither this one nor the old one are documented, so I'm not sure if this will behave the same.

Comment: @pimvdb [Noticed that already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468421/has-jquery-an-animating-event), however did not know that it is a *replacer* for the old function. Thanks, works well so far... (in jQuery's [updates blog](http://jquery.org/updates/page/9/) it is already flagged to be commented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, in jQuery's [updates-blog](http://jquery.org/updates/page/9/), this is already flagged to be commented.